# How to call the usb tethering intent in android 4.0 and 3.0?

Tags: android, android-intent, tethering

I am developing an application for Android 3.0 and above. I want to communicate to a PC by tethering.

How do I call the "Wireless and networks-Tethering and portable hotspot Intent" by code to enable the tethering manually?

Comment: did you got an answer to this?

Answer (score 2):

Tested in 4.1.2, perhaps should work in 4.0 also.

```
Intent tetherSettings = new Intent();
tetherSettings.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.TetherSettings");
startActivity(tetherSettings);
```

Comment: Another way of doing the same thing  [via : http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=690616] // load tether setting dialog
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
ComponentName com = new ComponentName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.TetherSettings");
intent.setComponent(com);
startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 1):

> I guess there is no option to enable the tethering by the code

Correct.

> And any one could you please tell me how to call the "Wireless and networks-Tethering and portable hotspot" intent by code to enable the tethering manually.

There is no documented and supported `Intent` action to bring up this specific screen in the Settings app at this time.

Comment: Thanks. But is there any other alternative way to achieve this partially?

Answer (score -1):

this code just starts the tethering settings and clicks on the USB tethering checkbox (setting it on if it's off and vice versa).

```
adb shell am start -n com.android.settings/.TetherSettings && adb shell input keyevent 20 && adb shell input keyevent 20 && adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_ENTER && sleep 2 && adb shell input keyevent 4
```